# Why is using a SELECT inside IN() so expensive?

Tags: postgresql, optimization, subquery

If I have this schema:

```
create table orders (
         id integer, 
         primary key(id)
);
create table orderlines (
         id integer, 
         orderid integer, 
         primary key(id), 
         foreign key (orderid) references orders(id)
);
```

and these queries:

```
select * from orderlines where orderid in (1);
select * from orderlines where orderid in (select orderid from orders where orderid=1);
```

When I `explain` these, I get these results:

```
                         QUERY PLAN                         
------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on orderlines  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8)
   Filter: (orderid = 1)
(2 rows)

                               QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on orderlines  (cost=0.00..47362.65 rows=1130 width=8)
   Filter: (SubPlan 1)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4)
           One-Time Filter: (orderlines.orderid = 1)
           ->  Seq Scan on orders  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=0)
```

If I understand this correctly, PostgreSQL runs the subselect on each `orderlines` record, which is very suboptimal.

I would expect the subselect to be run first, and then inserted into the `in()` as a kind of array or so.

Why does the planner do this, and how could I make this construction faster?

Comment: probably you need index on `orderid` column and I'd add distinct at least to test

Comment: "how could I make this construction faster", is a `JOIN` not an option, or is this more of a question why the optimizer created a slow query plan?

Comment: `faster` suggests that the current query is slow. Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for both queries? That also gives us information about the current performance, not just the plan. An index on orderid would be useful anyway.

Comment: 1) You should add `ANALYZE` to the plan to get actual timings. 2) [IN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN): *The right-hand side is a parenthesized subquery, which must return exactly one column. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each row of the subquery result.* 3) You already have the answer just select on the `orderid` directly.

Comment: Since orders doesn't have a column named orderid, that column refers to the column in the outer table.  That makes the query pretty dumb, and the planner just doesn't bother to optimize for such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the 2nd query in a subquery you use condition "orderid=1", but there is no column "orderid" in table orders however it exists in orderlines.
So it's a correlated query.

They both probably return the same result, but in the 2nd one there is a product join the 1st table on the 2nd table.

If you change orderid in subquery to id, the plan is going to be better:
Query:

```
select * from orderlines where orderid in (select id from orders where id=1);
```

Plan

```
    Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.28..29.80 rows=1 width=8)
  ->  Seq Scan on orderlines  (cost=0.00..21.50 rows=1 width=8)
        Filter: (orderid = 1)
  ->  Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4)
        Index Cond: (id = 1)
```